# Java example for New-AzStorageBlobSASToken

Tags: azure, azure-java-sdk

I'm trying to write java code to implement the same functionality that is provided by `New-AzStorageBlobSASToken`.  Is there any example that I can refer?

Answer (score 0):

`New-AzStorageBlobSASToken` generates a SAS token for an Azure storage blob. If you're using version 12 of Storage SDK for Java, you can accomplish this by using [`BlobServiceSasSignatureValues`](https://azuresdkdocs.blob.core.windows.net/$web/java/azure-storage-blob/12.0.0/com/azure/storage/blob/sas/BlobServiceSasSignatureValues.html) class.

Comment: I'm using java 8

Comment: You need to tell Storage SDK version please.